# Flutter how to make a row to stick at the bottom

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm currently working on a card that requires this bar to be at the bottom. But I tried many ways like a scaffold and still can't get it to be at the bottom.

```
                      Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                        child: Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            border: Border(
                                top: BorderSide(color: Color(0xF6F6F6F6))),
                          ),
                          child: Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Container(
                                  height: 30,
                                  child: FlatButton.icon(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    icon: Icon(Icons.bookmark_border,
                                        size: 18, color: Colors.black38),
                                    label: Text('Bookmark',
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 13,
                                            color: Colors.black54)),
                                    onPressed: () {},
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Container(
                                  height: 30,
                                  child: FlatButton.icon(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    icon: Icon(Icons.share,
                                        size: 18, color: Colors.black38),
                                    label: Text('Share',
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 13,
                                            color: Colors.black54)),
                                    onPressed: () {},
                                  ),
                                )
                              ])),
                      )],
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7moXw.jpg)

Comment: which one you want at the bottom

Comment: Wrap this align widget inside a container, give the height equal to your card height.

Comment: @RaguSwaminathan like inside the screenshot the "Bookmarks" and "Share" row

Comment: @meditat after adding the container the row is still does not stick to the bottom

Comment: use stack() to keep it sticky

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the **Row** in a **Column** and above the **Row** you have an **Expanded** wrapping the widget. In this case, I used a **Container** and I set the color to orange.

```
class BarStaysDown extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.orange,
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              color: Colors.white,
              child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      height: 30,
                      child: FlatButton.icon(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        icon: Icon(Icons.bookmark_border,
                            size: 18, color: Colors.black38),
                        label: Text('Bookmark',
                            style:
                                TextStyle(fontSize: 13, color: Colors.black54)),
                        onPressed: () {},
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: 30,
                      child: FlatButton.icon(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        icon: Icon(Icons.share, size: 18, color: Colors.black38),
                        label: Text('Share',
                            style:
                                TextStyle(fontSize: 13, color: Colors.black54)),
                        onPressed: () {},
                      ),
                    )
                  ]
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The ouput:
[image]

Comment: Nice! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end` to the row.

Hope it helped.

Comment: Yeah I have tried that one before, and that one doesn't really work.

Answer (score 0):

Without more information I am not sure that what I suggest will work. But you can use a **Stack** widget in combination with **Align** to achieve what you want. The stack [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html) with examples, check this article about [indexed stacks](https://medium.com/flutter-community/a-deep-dive-into-stack-in-flutter-3264619b3a77).